# Update billing address inserts javascript string in the address

Tags: javascript, upgrade, address, billing

when I hit update the billing address during checkout I get this string from legacy-build.min.js inserted into the address:

> function e(F,E){var D=0;try{this._each(function(H){F.call(E,H,D++)})}catch(G){if(G!=$break){throw G}}return this}, function y(G,F,E){var D=-G,H=[],I=this.toArray();if(G<1){return I}while((D+=G)F?1:0}).pluck("value")}, function w(){return s.call(this,0)}, function z(){var E=Prototype.K,D=$A(arguments);if(Object.isFunction(D.last())){E=D.pop()}var F=[this].concat(D).map($A);return this.map(function(H,G){return E(F.pluck(G))})}, function p(){return this.length}, function z(){return"["+this.map(Object.inspect).join(", ")+"]"}, function reverse() { [native code] }, function forEach() { [native code] }, function r(){this.length=0;return this}, function f(){return this[0]}, function l(){return this[this.length-1]}, function o(){return this.select(function(B){return B!=null})}, function A(){return this.inject([],function(C,B){if(Object.isArray(B)){return C.concat(B.flatten())}C.push(B);return C})}, function n(){var B=s.call(arguments,0);return this.select(function(C){return !B.include(C)})}, function q(B){return this.inject([],function(E,D,C){if(0==C||(B?E.last()!=D:!E.include(D))){E.push(D)}return E})}, function v(B){return this.uniq().findAll(function(C){return B.detect(function(D){return C===D})})}, function w(){return s.call(this,0)}

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Remove _.values for currentBillingAddress().street in `<text args="_.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ')"/><br/>` in the file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

Change this file by copying the file into the app folder with the same path. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Weird bug, i also found this and fix it like:

**In files:**

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```

and

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout-address-search/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```

replace

```
_.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ')
```

BY

```
_.values(currentBillingAddress().street).slice(0,3).join(', ')
```

this is a hackish workaround - this bug is due to Object values to array conversion and it seems earlier browser versions were only picking values inside currentBillingAddress() Object , but now in case of issue it seems lodash.values is also adding prototype objects of an object as items in array,
check Lodash version and see if you can fallback/upgrade to different one.

Regards
Deep Kamal Singh